# "Get-AzureStorageFile -Share $s -Path" not working when there is a space in folder name

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I started learning azure storage. I am using `Get-AzureStorageFile $s –Path [foldername]` to get list of files and folders available in a folder. This is not working when the folder has white space in its name.

Comment: Did you try quoting the folder name? You can also try escaping the white space with the backtick character

Comment: Yes. Finally I tried with qoutes and it worked. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution you have to mention the the file path in quotes

Ex: `Get-AzureStorageFile $s –Path 'Folder Name/File Name'`